# How to make datepicker in jquery-ui disable sunday without affecting other values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to make a date picker which excludes Sundays. But, in my work, i don't know why it is not working. Any kind of help is appreciated.

thank you very much.

Here's my code

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td><label > Schedule Day : </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id='date' name="date" required></td>
        <script src="../../Script/jQuery/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Script/jQuery/jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
        <script>



        $("#date").datepicker({


            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: 7,
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:false,
            dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
            inline: true,
            beforeShowDay: noSunday;
        });

        function noSunday(date){ 
            return [date.getDay() != 0, ''];
        }; 



        </script>   

        <td><input type='submit' id='btn' name="btnchkavlb" value="Check Availability"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use beforeShowDate event of DatePicker like below:

```
$(""#date"").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: 7,
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:false,
        dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
        inline: true,
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
var day = date.getDay();
return [day != 0,''];
}
})​​​​​;​
```

Comment: this works only for Sunday, how about the other values? e.g minDate, maxDate

Comment: wow, this works too, thanks <3, but I've remove the double quote at the beginning. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function noSunday(date){
    var day = date.getDay();
    return [(day > 0), ''];
};
```

and put your jquery code inside document.ready() block.

Comment: @Gilbert..beforeshowday event is correct... see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function noSunday(date){
    var d = date.getDay();
    return [(d > 0), ''];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry everyone, i've answered my own question x_x

welp i tried to put the beforeShowDay: noSunday, on the top part and it worked D:.

```
$("#date").datepicker({                                     
    beforeShowDay: noSunday,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: <?php echo $maxDaysBeforeSched;?>,
    changeMonth:true,
    changeYear:false,
    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    inline: true

});
```